# LEFT JOIN gives no results

Tags: mysql

```
So basically I have two tables:
```

u_contracts

```
+--------+---------+------------------------------+
| id     | user_id | reschedule_wait_confirm_till |
+--------+---------+------------------------------+
| 107742 |   19982 | 2012-08-08 17:10:41          |
|  38548 |    4622 | 2012-08-08 10:24:42          |
|  98483 |   36707 | 2012-08-08 21:39:08          |
|  45165 |   17632 | 2012-08-08 23:13:57          |
| 131285 |   47527 | 2012-08-08 08:33:58          |
| 131686 |   40194 | 2012-08-08 12:18:09          |
|  91749 |   11021 | 2012-08-08 12:22:05          |
+--------+---------+------------------------------+
```

restruct_mail_history

```
+----+---------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | _date               |
+----+---------+---------------------+
|  1 |   47527 | 2012-08-07 12:16:51 |
+----+---------+---------------------+
```

Now I need to select all user_id's from `u_contracts` that have date `reschedule_wait_confirm_till` for tomorrow and that have no todays entires in `restruct_mail_history`.

So far I have a working query like this:

```
SELECT
  uc.user_id
FROM
  u_contracts uc
WHERE
  uc._status = 6
  AND DATE( uc.reschedule_wait_confirm_till ) = DATE( ADDDATE( now(), 1 ) )
  AND uc.user_id NOT IN ( SELECT rmh.user_id FROM restruct_mail_history rmh WHERE DATE( rmh._date ) = DATE( now() ));
```

Output:

```
19982
4622
36707
17632
40194
11021
```

Now I don't like the SELECT statement in WHERE, so I was planing to make LEFT JOIN like this:

```
SELECT
  uc.user_id
FROM
  u_contracts uc
LEFT JOIN
  restruct_mail_history rmh
ON
  uc.user_id = rmh.user_id
WHERE
  uc._status = 6
  AND DATE( uc.reschedule_wait_confirm_till ) = DATE( ADDDATE( now(), 1 ) );
```

Output:

```
19982
4622
36707
17632
47527
40194
11021
```

Now this gives me all `u_contracts` result, but when I add the necessary parameter `AND DATE( rmh._date ) != DATE( now() )` it gives me absolutelu no results.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

*EDIT* If iI change the last line to `AND DATE( rmh._date ) = DATE( now() )`, it gives me only the results that **should not** be in the list, witch id correct. Why doesn't it work the opposite way?

Thank you already.

Comment: is there any nulls in the time date columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT uc.user_id
FROM u_contracts uc
     LEFT JOIN restruct_mail_history rmh
        ON uc.user_id = rmh.user_id
WHERE uc._status = 6 AND
      DATE( uc.reschedule_wait_confirm_till ) = DATE( ADDDATE( now(), 1) ) AND
      (rmh.user_id IS NULL OR DATE( rmh._date ) != DATE( now() ));
```

see here: [Visual Explanation Of Joins.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: This still gives me back all the results;

Comment: EDIT: you need to add `rmh.user_id IS NULL` in where clause.

Comment: Nope, it still hase the extra line. I updated the question with output examples and data from *both* tables.

Answer (score 0):

TRy this

```
SELECT 
  uc.user_id 
FROM 
  u_contracts uc 
LEFT JOIN 
  restruct_mail_history rmh 
ON 
  uc.user_id = rmh.user_id and   uc._status = 6 
  AND DATE( uc.reschedule_wait_confirm_till ) = DATE( ADDDATE( now(), -147 ) );
```

Comment: My mistake, It was there in the original question ;)